# Combine 4 variables into one variable name!

Tags: php

I dont think this is right...

```
$compname = $subformat_$subgame_$subname_$subseason;
```

What is the correct syntax?
THanks

Comment: Explain better please. Are you trying to concatenate 4 variables to get a string? Or the computed string is a variable name that exists and you want to get its value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

grossvogel solution is correct. You may also want to know this is good:

```
$compname = {$subformat.'_'.$subgame.'_'.$subname.'_'.$subseason};
```

But what you're trying to do looks really weird...
Why don't you use a four dimension array?

Answer (score 2):

```
$compname = implode('_', array ($subformat,$subgame,$subname,$subseason));
```

or

```
$compname = sprintf("%s_%s_%s_%s", $subformat, $subgame, $subname, $subseason);
```

or

```
$compname = "$subformat_$subgame_$subname_$subseason";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I can clarify the question being asked as I have the same.

The result is to create a previously set variable from combining multiple new variables.  Not to create a new one from multiple variables.

```
# variable pulled from database
$discover1qty = $r["discovery_1"];
.
.
.
.
$discover20qty = $r["discovery_20"];

$dc = "discover";
$endqty = "qty";
    for ($XS = 1; $XS <= 28; $XS++){

    # goal: add 3 variables together to get a database variable #
    $new_to_old = $dc + $XS + $endqty;
}

# When $new_to_old is called it translate to $discover20qty
```